# Identify variables in Expression does not work

Tags: pyomo

Given the following code based on Pyomo docs (https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer_reference/expressions/managing.html#identifying-components-and-variables and https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Expressions.html#expression-objects) I would expect to find a non-empty list, i.e. a list containing the variable `model.x`. Where is my misconception here?

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.core.expr.current import identify_variables

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var(initialize=1.0)
def _e(m,i):
    return m.x*i
model.e = pyo.Expression([1,2,3], rule=_e)

assert len(list(identify_variables(model.e, include_fixed=True))) > 0
```

Comment: `model.e.pprint()` shows the contents (3 expressions using `x`) of the indexed expression you create.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, this is what I ended up with to have a non-empty list if any expression uses a `Var`:

```py
from itertools import chain

import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.core.expr.current import identify_variables

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var(initialize=1.0)
def _e(m,i):
    return m.x*i
model.e = pyo.Expression([1,2,3], rule=_e)

assert len(list(chain(*(identify_variables(value) for value in list(model.e.values()))))) > 0
```